# is removeChild recursive?

Tags: javascript, dom

I create many new page elements (in some arbitrary hierarchy) using `document.createElement` and have been using `element.removeChild()` to erase elements I no longer want. I was wondering if this would correctly clean up all of the sub-elements as well, or if I should be using some sort of recursive function. Javascript uses a garbage collector, so I shouldn't need to worry about this, right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't, unless you're using a crappy browser :-) IE anyone?

Comment: Okay. Are there other perhaps more appropriate functions I should be using to delete entire nodes from the DOM?

Comment: Again, no - `element.removeChild()` is fine, unless you're using jQuery or another library, but they only wrap the native JavaScript function anyway.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Memory_leaks)'s an overview of the leaks that JamWaffles is referencing. As far as I know, it only affects IE6. But it seems like you're asking two different questions. Is removeChild recursive? No, the removed node retains its links to its children. Do you need to worry about it? No, the whole tree will get garbage collected if you no longer have references to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `element.removeChild(childElement)` *will* remove the nodes from your document tree. If you've got a reference to the element, however, the element will **not** be garbage-collected (GC).

*Consider:*
**Example 1** (horrible practice):

```
<body><script>
var d = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(d);
document.body.removeChild(d);
//The global scope won't disappear. Therefore, the variable d will stay,
// which is a reference to DIV --> The DIV element won't be GC-ed
</script></body>
```

**Example 2** (bad practice):

```
function foo(){
    var s = document.createElement("span");
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    s.innerHTML = "This could be a huge tree.";
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
        alert(eval(prompt("s will still refer to the element:", "s")));
        //Use the provided eval to see that s and s.innerHTML still exist
        // Because this event listener is added in the same scope as where
        // DIV `d` is created.
    }, true);
    document.body.removeChild(s);
}
foo();
```

**Example 3** (good practice):

```
function main(){
    //Functions defined below
    addDOM();
    addEvent();
    remove();
    //Zero variables have been leaked to this scope.

    function addDOM(){
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.id = "doc-rob";
        document.body.appendChild(d);
    }
    function addEvent(){
        var e = document.getElementById("doc-rob");
        document.body.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
            e && alert(e.tagName);
            //Displays alert("DIV") if the element exists, else: nothing happens.
        });
    }
    function remove(){
        var f = document.getElementById("doc-rob");
        f.parentNode.removeChild(f);
        alert(f);//f is still defined in this scope
        Function("alert('Typeof f = ' + typeof f);")(); //alert("Typeof f = undefined")
    }
}
main();
```

Comment: Nice answer. Regarding your second example most (if not all) modern javascript engines have very optimised GC, and the reason you think the element isn't GC's is precisely because you put the `eval` there! I.e. if you run the code with large objects and remove the `eval` statement and force GC (in a shell for example) you can see that they actually do clean up, because they can perform a static reference check and conclude that there is no longer a need to hold those objects, even if conventional lexical scoping defines them as part of the scope chain.

Comment: What I'm saying is, in most modern browsers the second example is not problematic at all (assuming you take out that `eval`).